# Avoiding script crash - gspread

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets-api, gspread

Recently I had to run a pretty long script using gspread. The script runs for more than one hour and updates many worksheets. Because it runs for so long, I am encountering two errors, that don't appear for regular scripts that run for up to 3 minutes or something like that.

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXXXXXXXXXX'.", 'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 'quota_limit_value': '60', 'quota_location': 'global', 'consumer': 'projects/XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'quota_metric': 'sheets.googleapis.com/read_requests', 'quota_limit': 'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerUser'}}, {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links': [{'description': 'Request a higher quota limit.', 'url': 'https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota'}]}]}
```

I actually solved this one using the following code:

```
t_0 = time.perf_counter()
api_requests_log = list()


def api_requests_timer():
    t_now = time.perf_counter() - t_0
    api_requests_log.append(t_now)
    requests_last_60_secs = list(filter(lambda x: x >= t_now - 60, api_requests_log))
    if len(requests_last_60_secs) > 45:
        sleep_time = 60 - (t_now - requests_last_60_secs[0])
        print(
            f'Sleeping the process for {sleep_time:.2f} seconds to avoid hitting Google Spreadsheet API requests limit')
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
    return None
```

If I paste the function `api_requests_timer()` before every request sent to Google Spreadsheet API, the function will measure how many API requests the script did in the last 60 seconds, and sleep the script for a few seconds if the number of the requests is close to the limit. But I don't know if that is an elegant solution, for sure it is not the practical one.

The other problem that I have encountered is connected with random connection loss, which causes the entire script to crash - `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`. After getting this error, I normally just run the code again and it works fine, but it is complicated with longer jobs.

I was thinking about a similar solution to the one I did for the previous problem, but the only thing that comes to my mind is writing the executable code as a function, then using `Try ... Except ConnectionResetError` block with the function inside both blocks. However, it complicates the script which is already complex enough... My second idea was to write a decorator that could solve both problems and could be pasted somehow into the *gspread* library, but to be honest I don't know if that's the right direction. (I am not a decorator expert). If someone encountered similar problems I would appreciate the opinions and possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

recently a new `Client` has been introduced, the `BackOffClient` it can be passed to one of the 2 functions: `gspread.auth.oauth` and `gspread.auth.service_account` in order to use that client instead of the regular one.

That client will check the API return code and sleep each time you reach the quota. If the sleep it not long enough it will sleep twice longer.

That will help your first case but can't solve it.
Because due to quota limits you must wait and the client cannot wait for too long and must stop at some points. Be aware that will make your script wait for some time at some point.

Here is an example on how to use it:

```py
import gspread
client = gspread.oauth(client_factory=gspread.BackoffClient)
```

About the second case, you can't do much, the Google server stop the TCP connection for some reasons. And does tell us why.

There might be some possible Acton i leave it to anyone with more networking knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check this BackoffClient!